# Can't redirect old domain to new domain with htaccess rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I was trying to redirect old domain to new domain with htaccess, I did with another domain, trying the same code and worked, but with this domain I can't.

I want to redirect [rucab.es](http://rucab.es) to residenciarucab.es

Code that I tried with another domain and with this domain don't work:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?rucab\.es [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.residenciarucab.es/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Though the code you tried certainly could be writte better it _should_ work. So the question is what differs to the situation you yourself claimed where it works. Maybe the rewriting module is not loaded? Maybe you placed that dynamic configuration file at a wrong location or with wrong permissions? You will need to debug, we cannot do that for you. The place to start is your http server's error log file. What does it say what the issue is?

Comment: How I can see if the rewriting module is loaded or not? I dont think that I placed it in wrong location, and the permissions are good.

Comment: As written: you need to take a look into your http server's error log file. That is what that log file is written for...

Comment: The log server file didn't show any error.

Comment: I doubt that, actually. An apache http server's error log file cannot be empty. Are you really certain that you checked the right file?